# Windows 10 Pro Recovery Disk after upgrade from Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, upgrade

I have upgraded my new laptop from Windows 10 Home Single Language to Windows 10 Pro through Windows store by paying $100.I did not get any Pro Product key but my laptop was upgraded using digital entitlement. My curiosity is, if I now create a recovery disk of my Laptop which runs on Windows 10 Pro now, what edition of Windows 10 will be installed if at some point of time in future I re install the OS using the recovery disk. Windows 10 Pro or still Windows 10 home?
Thanks.

Comment: I should point out, you were suppose to get a key, the license you purchased isn't controlled by a digital entitlement.  If you did not recieve a key you should check the Windows Store order history, so you actually have that key in the future.  You will need that key in the future order future installation of Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but as per Microsoft recovery will be made of win 10 pro using my existing product key

Comment: What? Your comment is confusing

Comment: I did something similar and called Microsoft about not getting a key with my purchased upgrade. They told me to use just use the key printed on the MS sticker on back of the computer for the original OS.

Comment: What I meant there was, I asked the same question in Microsoft Community as well. And reply by Microsoft is that "If I create a recover disk with Windows 10 Pro upgraded" the recovery will install Windows 10 Pro not Windows 10 Home as the default OS.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 Pro, if you used the **Recovery Drive** feature to create the media